# storing result value of selenium assertElementPresent

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am attempting to store the result value (true or false) of the `assertElementPresent` method in the variable `A` using this Selenese syntax:

```
storeEval | var b=assertElementPresent(//table[1]//tr[${i}]/td[1]/input[1]) | A
```

The syntax is incorrect.  What syntax would I use to make this statement work?

Comment: Have you tried anything else?

Comment: To make my question clearer, let me explain a bit more.  I'm using sel blocks add-in in firefox. I am trying to create a conditional test for an if then block. My code looks like this:    if | assertElementPresent(//table[1]//tr[${i}]/td[1]/input[1]) |
for | i=1; i &lt;= 3; i++ |i
check | //table[1]//tr[${i}]/td[1]/input[1] |
endIf | |
endFor | |